# Manually normalizing JSON

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using Ember-Data's DS.ActiveModelSerializer. There's an instance where I'm getting data outside of the usual Ember channels, but it still needs to be normalized. I've been attempting to hack together a solution with code like:

```
DS.ActiveModelSerializer.normalize('model', response.data)
```

But that results in the error:

```
DS.ActiveModelSerializer.normalize is not a function
```

Is it even possible to call a serializer outside of an adapter? If so, how is it managed?

Comment: Also could you give us a code example of the json you are have trouble getting into your ember app. Second you are able to setup a per model adapter for ember data. Have a look here https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#per-type-adapters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`normalize` is not a class method of the serializer, so you can't call it via `DS.ActiveModelSerializer`.

You can access the serializer from elsewhere though if you have access to the store (which you do in route and controller objects by default, using this.store).

The store has a `serializerFor` method, which  takes a single argument which is the name of the model. For example, you could do this:

`var serializer = this.store.serializerFor('model');`

You can then use `serializer.normalize(...)` as you wish.

Comment: I'm assuming the method call should look something like `serializer.normalize('modelName', json)`? When I try that, I get this error: `TypeError: type.eachAttribute is not a function`. Perhaps I need to send something else in the params?

Comment: The default implementation in ActiveModelSerializer is something like normalize(type, hash), yes. The type needs to match the string name of a type which derives from DS.Model, so if your model was defined as App.MyCustomModel = DS.Model.extend({...}), you'd pass "my-custom-model" as the type. Your error message sounds like the type is invalid or not derived from DS.Model, since eachAttribute is a method used to iterate over all properties defined as DS.attr(...) in your model definition.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly the tip I needed. In the end, I just referenced the model directly, like `serializer.normalize(App.MyCustomModel, json)`

Comment: Glad I could help. Generally Ember doesn't mind whether you use the fully-qualified class name (as you've said you're doing) or the dasherized version as in my example, though I seem to remember reading somewhere that the dasherized version is preferred now - don't ask me why though!